# download.file not working when the wait time is too long

Tags: r

I have an internal webpage executing SQL queries (loading for over 6 minutes) before download starts, and I gets an error when I try to use download.file (download.file works fine with other similar internal webpages).

Below is my console message, I have hid the URL

```
Error in download.file(url = ., destfile = paste(getwd(), "/input/", file.name,  : 
  cannot open URL ''
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(url = ., destfile = paste(getwd(), "/input/", file.name,  :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The operation timed out'
Called from: download.file(url = ., destfile = paste(getwd(), "/input/", 
    file.name, sep = ""), quiet = TRUE)
```

Comment: This isn’t really a problem of `download.file`, or R, for that matter. Fix the server. Having to wait six minutes to open a connection without timing out would tax most web clients. It’s completely unreasonable. That said, check the `extra` parameter of the function. You can pass a larger timeout to the underlying connection handler.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph thanks for your comment, but I am not sure how to add connect timeout to extra parameter in download.file, I have tried options(timeout = 6000) in front of the code, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to read the documentations of the function, as well as of the underlying tool that you use for the connection (either curl or wget).

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph Sorry, but I don't think this option works for me since the only workable download method is "wininet", thanks for your help.